# Missing Data Mixed Effects Modelling for Repeated Measures

Tags: mixed-model, missing-data

I am currently working on a problem where I try to explain within subject variance in an outcome using multiple other variables. In R setting up the model looks like this

```
lmFull<-lmer(outcome ~ (1|subject) + pred1 + pred2 +pred3 ... pred40)
```

The problem is that there is some mild missingness in each predictor variables. Thus, using listwise deletion (the default setting of lmer) many cases are lost, since due to the number of predictors chances are high that at least one is missing.

I have googled this problem but can only find examples claiming that this is not an issue in mixed modelling since it uses the long format. This, however, is only true if there are few predictors.

One obvious solution would be to use FIML ([Full Information Maximum Likelihood](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/54779/203941)). However, some of my predictors are ordinal and thus not normally distributed. Setting up a valid joint distribution for all my predictors will be very cumbersome.

One quick and dirty solution might be to impute the values with the within subject means.

Any thoughts? Is there a recommended approach?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Imputation using within subject means isn't a great idea because it will result in biased (too small) standard errors and possibly biased estimates.

Assuming that the data are missing at random, a much better idea is to use multiple imputation. The `mice` package in R has the capability to impute continuous variables in a mixed efects framework with a single random effect (grouping variable) - just specify `2l.norm` as the grouping variable. For example, suppose our analysis model is

```
> require(mice)
> require(lme4)
> m0 <- lmer(teachpop~sex+texp+popular + (1|school), data=popmis)
> confint(m0)

                  2.5 %     97.5 %
.sig01       0.44905533 0.62574295
.sigma       0.54368549 0.59259188
(Intercept)  2.03118933 2.67864796
sex         -0.07108881 0.09183821
texp         0.03024598 0.06505065
popular      0.22257646 0.32572600
```

Due to missingness in the predictor `popular` this model may be biased. So we will use multiple imputation:

```
> ini <- mice(popmis, maxit=0)
> (pred <- ini$pred)

         pupil school popular sex texp const teachpop
pupil        0      0       0   0    0     0        0
school       0      0       0   0    0     0        0
popular      1      1       0   1    1     0        1
sex          0      0       0   0    0     0        0
texp         0      0       0   0    0     0        0
const        0      0       0   0    0     0        0
teachpop     0      0       0   0    0     0        0
```

This is the default predictor matrix for the imputation model. Only `popular` has missing values, and we are going to impute them using a mixed model where `school` is the grouping factor, and the other variables are fixed effects. To do this, we use `-2` to tell `mice` that school is the grouping variable, and `2` for the fixed effects:

```
> pred["popular",] <- c(0, -2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0)
> (pred)
```

So now we have:

```
         pupil school popular sex texp const teachpop
pupil        0      0       0   0    0     0        0
school       0      0       0   0    0     0        0
popular      0     -2       0   2    2     2        0
sex          0      0       0   0    0     0        0
texp         0      0       0   0    0     0        0
const        0      0       0   0    0     0        0
teachpop     0      0       0   0    0     0        0
```

We have set up the predictor matrix, so we can now create 10 multiply imputed datasets using the `2l.norm` method to impute values for `popular`

```
> imp <- mice(popmis, meth = c("","","2l.norm","","","",""), pred = pred, maxit=10, m = 10)
```

Now we run the mixed model on each of the imputed datasets:

```
> fit <- with(imp, lmer(teachpop~sex+texp+popular + (1|school)))
```

...and pool the results:

```
> summary(pool(fit))

                   est          se         t        df     Pr(>|t|)      lo 95      hi 95 nmis
(Intercept) 2.73951576 0.165053863 16.597708 1991.5874 0.000000e+00 2.41581941 3.06321211   NA
sex         0.08620420 0.031042794  2.776947  915.1865 5.599307e-03 0.02528087 0.14712753    0
texp        0.05682495 0.009713717  5.849970 1991.4452 5.733929e-09 0.03777484 0.07587506    0
popular     0.16696926 0.018760706  8.899945 1980.9159 0.000000e+00 0.13017647 0.20376205  848
```

Answer (score 3):

In his book Stef van Buuren describes the difficulties in multilevel modelling when a level-1 or level-2 predictor is missing. He advices to use 2l.pmm from `miceadds`, and setting the value to 3 in the predictor matrix as outlined [here](https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/sec-mlguidelines.html#7.10.4) under '7.10.2 Random intercepts, missing level-1 predictor'. This adds the cluster means for the imputed variable to the model. According to [this](https://bookdown.org/mwheymans/bookmi/multiple-imputation-models-for-multilevel-data.html#the-predictormatrix), a value of 3 in the predictor matrix of mice means 'imputation model with a fixed effect, random intercept and cluster means'.

This seems to be an update on [this tutorial](https://www.gerkovink.com/miceVignettes/Multi_level/Multi_level_data.html) where the accepted answer is described. As Stef van Buuren also mentions, alternatives would be ad-hoc solutions, eg. listwise deletion (in your case obviously does not make sense), or multilevel imputation with joint models, eg with the R package `jomo`.

P.S.: To add to OP's question of long vs wide: Stef van Buuren also mentions that mixed models can handle missing data in the **outcome** easily (see [here](https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/sec-missmult.html)).

> The multilevel model is actually “made to solve” the problem of missing values in the **outcome**. (...) Missing outcome data are easily handled in modern likelihood-based methods (...). Mixed-effects models can be fit with maximum-likelihood methods, which take care of missing data in the **dependent variable**. This principle can be extended to address missing data in explanatory variables in (multilevel) software for structural equation modeling like Mplus (Muthén, Muthén, and Asparouhov 2016) and gllamm (Rabe-Hesketh, Skrondal, and Pickles 2002).

Comment: Are you suggesting this as an alternative to @Robert Long's suggested method? At least part of your answer seems to be a question - in which case please post it as a question instead (you will probably want to link to this question in your new question, and make it clear what you want to clarify).

Comment: i guess it's an update to the accepted answer, so i changed my answer accordingly.